# T420 Camera Crashes when moving display

Tags: thinkpad, integrated-camera

I have a Lenovo T420 and have some funky issue with my Integrated Camera. The camera seems to crash whenever I pull the display closer towards the keyboard. And if the display makes a 90 degree angle or less with the keyboard it never works.

Can anybody help me shed some light on this weird problem and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a electrical short in the hardware - meaning there is a loose wire or contact somewhere inside the laptop case.  Its probably a good idea to contact Lenovo's support to see what they have to say about it.  If the laptop is is still under warranty, obviously they will fix it.  Even if it isnt, it might be a known issue and they may still be able to tell you how to fix it, or direct you to an authorized support center who can.